# External library errors c++

Tags: c++, dll, extern

I got some problem with compiling DLL file project. There are 2 files CDLL.h and CDLL.cpp:

CDLL.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace CDLL {

    class CDLL
    {

        static unsigned char TransLut[256];

    public:
        __declspec(dllexport) void build_lookup_table ( int contr);
        __declspec(dllexport) bool Contrast(HBITMAP * phBitmap, int iCount);
    };
}
```

CDLL.cpp:

```
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include "CDLL.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

namespace CDLL
{
    void CDLL::build_lookup_table(int contr)
    {
        float step, step_value;

        for (int i=0; i < 256; i++)
            TransLut[i] = i;

        if (contr > 0)
        {
            unsigned int MinBin = contr;
            unsigned int MaxBin = 255 - contr;

            step = sqrt((double)contr)/contr;
            step_value = 0.0;

            for (int i = 0; i < MinBin; i++)
            {
                TransLut[i] = (unsigned char)step_value;
                step_value += step;
            }

            step = 256.0f / (float)(MaxBin-MinBin);

            for (int i = MinBin; i <= MaxBin; i++)
            {
                if (step_value > 255.0f)
                {
                    step_value = 255.0f;
                    step = 0.0f;
                }

                TransLut[i] = (unsigned char)step_value;
                step_value += step;
            }

            for (int i = MaxBin + 1; i < 256; i++)
                TransLut[i] = 255;

        }
        else if (contr < 0)
        {
                step = (256.0+(float)(contr*2))/256.0;
                step_value = (float)contr * -1.0;

                for (int i = 0;i < 256; i++)
                {
                    TransLut[i] = (unsigned char)step_value;
                    step_value += step;
                }
        }
    }

    bool CDLL::Contrast(HBITMAP * phBitmap, int iCount) 
    {
        BITMAP bm;
        BYTE * pBits;
        RGBQUAD * pRgb;
        WORD wByteCount;
        int i, iPixels, gray;

        build_lookup_table(iCount);

        // Take BITMAP structure from HBITMAP

        GetObject(*phBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);

        // Calculate bytes to read

        wByteCount = bm.bmHeight * (2 * ((bm.bmWidth * bm.bmBitsPixel + 15) / 16));

        // Alocate momory for bits od pixels and get pointers

        pBits = (BYTE *) malloc(wByteCount);
        GetBitmapBits(*phBitmap, wByteCount, pBits);

        // Convert pointer to byte to pointer to RGBQUAD

        pRgb = (RGBQUAD *) pBits;

        // Operate on pixel's colors

        iPixels = wByteCount / (bm.bmBitsPixel / 8);

        for(int i = 0; i < iPixels; i++, pRgb++)
        {
            gray = (pRgb->rgbRed + pRgb->rgbGreen + pRgb->rgbBlue) / 3;
            int k = TransLut[gray]-gray;

            pRgb->rgbRed   = min(pRgb->rgbRed   + k, 255);
            pRgb->rgbGreen = min(pRgb->rgbGreen + k, 255);
            pRgb->rgbBlue  = min(pRgb->rgbBlue  + k, 255);
        }

        SetBitmapBits(*phBitmap, wByteCount, pBits);

        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

The thing I do not get why I get such an errors like:

1. error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'HBITMAP' CDLL.h
2. error C2511: 'bool CDLL::CDLL::Contrast(HBITMAP *,int)' : overloaded
   member function not found in 'CDLL::CDLL' CDLL.cpp

Isn't #2 about the declaration of method in header file? How should I fix this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HBITMAP` type is a [windows specific type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In your code it seems like you have forgotten to include the appropriate header. This may be the problem.

Comment: Of course I can't see whether it is included in stdafx. I'll delete the answer if this is the case.

Comment: You are right, but lack of header isn't the reason of #1, #2, #5 errors I mentioned.

Comment: Sometimes these errors appear because of other things. Fx error #2 could be because the compiler can't understand the definition of the Contrast function and tries to explain this by saying that the statement should have ended before. This could at least be the reason.

Comment: Including windows.h changed a lot, edited 1st post. I bet it is something in CDLL.h in method declaration arguments, I do not know if they are put properly. I haven't been using C++ for a while.

Comment: @user2904111 You need to `#include <windows.h>` in your DLL's header; `HBITMAP` is undefined there, so your method signature isn't valid. After that, you might need to `#define` your `min` function if it's not defined in `stdafx.h` (I'm checking your code in GCC, so I don't have that header available right now).